# How to add double frame in tcolorbox?

Tags: chapters, tcolorbox, titlesec

Is it possible to add double frame in a tcolorbox? Actually I am trying to design a chapter using titlesec and tcolorbox which has two borders. Inner border colour will be white ( same as the page colour ) and the outer border colour will be cyan ( same as the box background colour) something like this.

[image]

This is the code which I was trying :

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myCyan}{HTML}{13C39D}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\filcenter}
{}
{0pt}
{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        colback = myCyan,
        fontupper=\color{white},
        boxrule=0pt,
        colframe=black!70!white,
        arc=0pt,
        outer arc=0pt,
        top=20pt,
        bottom=20pt,
        left=20pt,
        right=20pt,
        ]
        \begin{center}
            #1
        \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0cm}{0cm}
```

Comment: So all of your chapters are not numbered?

Comment: Yes, numbered. the image which i have provide is just for the demo purpose. Number will be at the begging of the chapter like this : 1. Android Tutorial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a start. The idea is to nest `tcolorbox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=green!50!blue,
    colframe=green!50!blue,
    left=1.5pt,right=1.5pt,top=1.5pt,bottom=-1.5pt,
    sharp corners,
    boxsep=0pt
]
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=green!50!blue,
    colframe=white,
    leftrule=1.5pt,rightrule=1.5pt,toprule=1.5pt,bottomrule=1.5pt,
    sharp corners,
    fontupper=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\Large\centering
]
Android tutorial
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now let's customize our chapter with it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myCyan}{HTML}{13C39D}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\filcenter}
{}
{0pt}
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=myCyan,
    colframe=myCyan,
    left=1.5pt,right=1.5pt,top=1.5pt,bottom=-1.5pt,
    sharp corners,
    boxsep=0pt
]
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=myCyan,
    colframe=white,
    leftrule=1.5pt,rightrule=1.5pt,toprule=1.5pt,bottomrule=1.5pt,
    sharp corners,
    fontupper=\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\centering
]
\thechapter. #1
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0cm}{0cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem lipsum}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

There's no need for nested `tcolorboxes`, you could use an `enhanced` box with an additional `borderline`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myCyan}{HTML}{13C39D}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\filcenter}
{}
{0pt}
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    colback=myCyan,
    colframe=myCyan,
    boxsep=5pt,
    sharp corners,
    borderline={1.5pt}{3pt}{white},
    colupper=white,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge,
    halign upper=center
]
\thechapter. #1
\end{tcolorbox}%
}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0cm}{0cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem lipsum}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]